# Why does the Default Cube's Mesh have a Reversed Vertex Index Position?

Tags: mesh, vertices

The new cubes that are added to the scene via (**Add** -> **Cube**) have a reversed index position. I would have to apply  a negative one (-1) scale to all the new cubes so they are consistent with the default cube's vertex position index sequence. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: i think you have to ask the developers for the reason... ;)

Comment: In case you want or don't know, you can enable the *Indices* overlay option by activating *Developer Extras* in the interface preferences. The *Indices* option will be below the *Mesh Edit Mode* in *Viewport Overlays*.

Comment: @Chris yes i should! Hulifier hey thanks for the info!